# Android button with image above line of text that scales correctly

Tags: android

How can I create a single clickable button where image is above a line of text. Image should fill parent height while maintaining correct aspect ratio for image and leaving room for text. Example:

[image: Android image button with caption]

This solution is almost perfect but the image does not scale to make room for text if parent is too small.

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/myimage"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

EDIT: 
I want to use the above xml fragment and include it in horizontal scroll view like so (2 rows of buttons). If I get scaling to work I'd define each buttons `text` and `drawableTop` in this parent xml layout file

[image]

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <include layout="@layout/custom_button" />
            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/custom_button"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Attach your full xml please

Comment: please attach screenshot of xml preview

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin edited with more context of what I'm tryign to do

Comment: use constraint layout you then you can easily find a way